# Message Box Pops up more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, timer, messagebox

I have the following code, the timerStart method that will call some functions every second, the problem is when the condition is true in checkSigning method, the pop up appears more than once.. How can i possibly fix this? Can someone help me :<

```
  public void timerStart()
    {
        DispatcherTimer updaterTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        updaterTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(updaterTimer_Tick);
        updaterTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        updaterTimer.Start();

    }

    private void updaterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Time.Content = "Time : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        exist = saved_settings();
        if (exist)
        {
            settingForToday();
            checkSigningAvailable();
            setSigning(signingAvailable = getSigning());
        }
        else
        {
            ongoing.Content = "Event : No Event";
            sign_in.Content = "Sign-in Time : ";
            sign_out.Content = "Sign-out Time : ";
        }

    }

    public void checkSigningAvailable()
    {
        if (dt_signing_in.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0)
        {
            if ((!InisOver && signing.Equals("in")) || (!InisOver && signing.Equals("in_out") && !OutisOver))
            {
                disableSigningIn(OutisOver.ToString(),this.event_id);
            }
        }

        if (dt_signing_out.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0)
        {
            if ((!OutisOver && signing.Equals("out")) || (!OutisOver && signing.Equals("in_out") && InisOver))
            {
                disableSigningOut(InisOver.ToString(),this.event_id);

            }
        }
    }


    public void disableSigningOut(string In,string event_id)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Signing out is over!", "No more signing out!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            connection.Open();
            string sign = In + ",True";
            string query = "update data_storage set data_details = '" + sign + "' where data_name = 'Signing';";
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Close();
            connection.Close();
            sign_out.Content = "Sign-out Time : Over";
            string query2 = concatQuery(getIDnumberAttendance(event_id));
            updateAbsences(query2);
    }
```

Comment: You could try setting a flag when you enter `disableSigningOut()` and clearing it when you exit the method.  Then add a check at the beginning of the method (before setting the flag) to abort if the flag has already been set.

Comment: it doesn't work :< can you make me the flagging you meant?

Comment: Additional info : If i have tabs, if i stay in the home tab it pops once, but when i switch into different tabs while the condition is not yet true, that's when it pops more than once

Answer (score 1):

You can Stop the timer while you execute the tick and start it again on the end. The only down side you will have is that the time will be measure form the moment you finish you updaterTimer_Tick execution - but you may also consider it as a benefit.

```
private void updaterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updaterTimer.Stop();
    Time.Content = "Time : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    exist = saved_settings();
    if (exist)
    {
        settingForToday();
        checkSigningAvailable();
        setSigning(signingAvailable = getSigning());
    }
    else
    {
        ongoing.Content = "Event : No Event";
        sign_in.Content = "Sign-in Time : ";
        sign_out.Content = "Sign-out Time : ";
    }
    updaterTimer.Start();
}
```